# jQuery Show and Hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I have a page what will have a few buttons on it and on a click of a button I basically need it to swap divs out - I have them wrapped in a parent `div` with an `id` and then each `div` that will be replaced will get it's own `id` as well. I got this code to work for swapping, but it will be tedious and not good code at all to do this if we end up with 30 or so pairings.

So how do I clean this up so on a click, the active div is set to `display: none`, and the one clicked is set to `display: block`?

Here is my jQuery code that is working for now. For this I want the `macaroni` to display and the `farfalle` to hide.

```
$('#macaroniButton').click(function(){
    $('#macaroni').toggle();
    $('#farfalle').toggle();
});
```

```html
<div id="topchanger">
    <div id="farfalle">
        .....
    </div>
    <div id="macaroni">
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  <div class="circlerow">

     <div class="circlepasta" id="macaroniButton">
        ......
     </div>

     <div class="circlepasta" id="AnotherButton">
        ......
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use some sort of parent/child selectors depending where the buttons are.

Comment: Can you add the `#macaroniButton` elements' HTML to the question please.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I was just adding that sorry.

Comment: It would be very helpfull if you could share a jsFiddle to show you example working.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with this. Expand my answer accordingly.

```
     $('#macaroniButton').click(function(){

           $("#macaroni").show().siblings('div').hide();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a class to all the `div`  that you want to `show`/`hide` and before handling a click, hide all div with that class. Let's say you give it a class 'item':

```
<div id="topchanger">
    <div id="farfalle" class="item">
        .....
    </div>
    <div id="macaroni" class="item">
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

and your javascript will be:

```
$('div.item').click(function(){
  $('div.item').hide();
  $(this).show();
});
```

Note that `$(this)` refers to the item that was just clicked.

Hope it hepls